# How to access a constant nested function's parameter in javascript?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I was asked this question in an assessment I took and was not able to figure it out. Would like to know possible solutions.

#### Question:

> Write one Javascript statement on the indicated line that will make the printed number always be between 10 and 20.
>
> ```
> let x = 2;
> let y = 8;
> const a = function(b) {
>     return function(c) {
>         return x + y + Math.abs(b) + c;
>     };    
> };
>
> // Statement will go here
>
> const fn = a(x);
> x = 4;
> console.log(fn(Math.random() * 10));
> ```

I've tried assigning different values to variable `y`. But I think the culprit is to know what variable `c` would be in the nested function. Note that `c` would always be a number between 0 and 10 (as `Math.random()` is between 0 and 1, then multiplied by 10).

Comment: what is the part, you got and what is the question with it?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? What is the question?

Comment: "How to access" is not a clear question.

Comment: What's the task? Have you thought of reassigning `Math.random`  ... ;)

Comment: Sorry, the question didn’t make the code block as it was a commented statement. I just added it: Write one Javascript statement on the indicated line that will make the printed number always be between 10 and 20.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already concluded correctly that the argument passed to `fn` is a random number between 0 and 10, which is `c` in the expression that the call to `fn` will evaluate: `x + y + Math.abs(b) + c`

So if `fn` must return a number between 10 and 20, then `x + y + Math.abs(b)` must equal 10.

We also see that the global variable `x` is set to 4 at a time that we cannot change it any more, but still before the call to `fn`, so that means `y + Math.abs(b)` must equal 6.

Now this gives us already a hint: as it stands, `y` is 8, which makes the conclusion in the previous paragraph impossible. So we *must* alter `y`. It is not yet too late, since the value of `y` will only be read when `fn` is called.

So what is `Math.abs(b)`? The local variable `b` is set when `a` is called. `a` is called with `x`, which at the time of that call is still 2. So `Math.abs(b)` is 2, and so we can derive that `y` must be 4.

One obvious way to make `y` to be 4 in one line:

```
y = 4;
```

(Alternatively, `y-=4`, `y>>=1`, `y/=2`, `y^=12`, ...etc)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to provide a creative answer, try:

```
Math.random = function() { return 1.345; };
```